# Power BI REST authentication and permissions

Tags: api, rest, azure, powerbi

I'm attempting to create a bridge between another service (as a data source) and Microsoft Power BI. However, I can't get the REST API to work properly.

So far I've succeeded in creating a web application in Azure AD, getting the Client ID and secret, receiving an access token for the API, but after this all I get is `403 Forbidden` with no error message. However, if I try to access the API with an expired token, I get an error message telling me that the token is expired.

I've read some posts on the subject, but they all suggest that the REST API cannot be accessed without having a user log in and access Power BI first, which isn't possible in a service-to-service application.

How do I properly access the service without any user interaction?

Here are the requests and responses, censored a little bit.

Request 1:

```
POST /[our domain].com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productiona; stsservicecookie=ests
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.3) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 203

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[client id]&client_secret=[client secret]&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi
```

Response 1:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-request-id: 52d6713c-d50b-4073-b030-aa10e33fdf27
client-request-id: 3aef4765-d602-46a6-a8ce-4b7792f678e5
x-ms-gateway-service-instanceid: ESTSFE_IN_209
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=productiona; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 08:24:29 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1243

{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"1456305870","not_before":"1456301970","resource":"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api","access_token":"[access token]"}
```

Request 2:

```
GET /v1.0/myorg/datasets HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [access token]
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.powerbi.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.3) GCDHTTPRequest
```

Response 2:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
RequestId: 803cc0cb-c65d-4212-9ab8-aed4ffa9862a
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 08:25:13 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: Hi onik, did you get any solution for getting access token. I am facing similar issue.

Comment: No, I didn’t investigate it any further, we decided to use Azure SQL to import the data to Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs you're using require a user's access token. They access content in a user's account. So if you don't have the access token, you'll keep getting forbidden. So what you need to do is get the access token with the user the first time. Then store the refresh token. Then use the refresh token to get new access tokens as needed. If the refresh token expires, you need to ask the user to sign in again.

Comment: I accepted this answer even though it's not completely without user interaction, but it's the best solution for the moment. I heard that MS is improving their authentication to allow pure service-to-service auth but it's not released yet.

Comment: @Lukasz P. Can you provide some inputs on this? How can I do refresh token? I am having similar issue. I am using some REST API it requires Cookie Aithentication. I am trying to figure out how to create a cookie from Power-bi. Any help?